Building JSX in a WordPress plugin, can't get Webpack to watch / build from assets folder into dist?
I started to create a new Wordpress plugin and want to know what is a good structure/way to implement a build of my all javascript files (keeping their directory structure in the dist/build folder) which are using JSX there (React, Wordpress JS packages ...).
I tried to use webpack for that, but can't configure it correctly to watch/build all js files in assets/js folder into dist/js.
The plugin structure
my-plugin
    |_assets
        |_js
            |_admin (inside JS files)
            |_helper (inside JS files)
            ...
    |_dist
        |_js (I want to have a same structure inside this folder)

webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './assets/js/admin/js1.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'js1.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js/admin')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js'],
    },
}

also created a .babelrc file
{
  "presets": [
    "@wordpress/babel-preset-default"
  ]
}


You'll want to share more details (eg. your plugin folder structure, webpack.config.js, etc) so others can help. Otherwise and without seeing some code at least all we can do is guess.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
